# How do I check the stability of a multiple pole feedback bandpass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, band-pass

Is it possible to find stability measures like phase margin or gain margin for a multiple feedback band pass filter?

The circuit is as shown below:

[image]

Comment: That circuit was generated by ADI's filter design wizard, and that shows the amplitude response, right? Does that look unstable to you?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Point is that you can of course set up an equation system using the model of an *ideal* opamp, derive the positions of the poles, then do the usual "region of convergence includes unit circle" etc tricks,  but this isn't an ideal opamp, so that equation system will get ugly very quickly, not be linear at all, dampened in ways that your ideal opamp can't represent, and be solvable only by a computer, anyway. So, use the simulation model of the opamp to begin with. The tool you're already using does that, but you might as well use SPICE and other circuit simulators.

Comment: Use a sim is what Marcus is saying and I agree.

Comment: @Andyaka I should have made this an answer, shouldn't I? Lemme fix that.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

That circuit was generated by ADI's filter design wizard, and that shows the amplitude response, right? Does that look unstable to you?

## Longer answer

Point is that you can of course set up an equation system using the model of an ideal opamp, derive the positions of the poles, then do the usual "region of convergence includes unit circle" etc tricks.

However, this isn't an ideal opamp, so that equation system will get ugly very quickly, not be linear at all, dampened in ways that your ideal opamp can't represent, and be solvable only by a computer, anyway. So, use the simulation model of the opamp to begin with. The tool you're already using does that, but you might as well use SPICE and other circuit simulators.

Comment: Yes , it is stable but this circuit output is connected to ADC and its impedance. So I wanted to test the effect of ADC impedance on the circuit.

Comment: This Circuit is a part of a signal chain so thought of checking the stability of individual opamps..

Comment: @Creative ADCs want to be driven by buffers with a drive strength so much larger than their own that they don't effectively matter for stability, or you're dealing with a broadband ADC with integrated amplifiers and want impedance matching instead, in which you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: And re: signal chain: that is a good idea, but really, an amplifier should have enough isolation of input from output that you can just cascade them without building a larger feedback across amplifiers.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I am not using breadboard ADC. The point is this circuit (it is just a representative circuit, cant post the actual one but it uses the same topology with different center frequency, designed with analog filter wizard) is a part of lock-in detector and output of this goes into the ADC. But for some reason output of this bandpass filter is bit distorted (kind of triangular). I checked the slew rate and closed-loop poles of the BPF and both of them were fine. So I thought maybe a deeper analysis is required so i switched to LTSpice for finding ROC of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it is not necessary to find the stability margin of a filter circuit as shown. We know that for a bandpass with a relatively high Q-value (Q>10) the closed-loop poles are rather close to the Im-axis of the s-plane - identical to a pretty low phase margin.

This is no surprise and does not contain any new information for the user. Moreover, you cannot change (improve) the margin without changing the desired closed-loop filter function.

Of course, this assumes that

- the design of the filter (and the calculation of the parts values) was done correctly, and
- a suitable opamp was selected for the circuit because - during the design process - the opamp is treated as ideal (infinite gain and no unwanted phase shift).

However, for a second-order allpole system (like your circuit) there is a direct relation between the filters Q-value and the phase margin. That means, we do not need loop gain simulation.

For example, for **Q=10** we have **PM=5.7 deg** and for **Q=20** the margin is **PM=2.86deg**